# Set Aruco coordinate system

Tags: opencv3.0, ros, aruco

Hey there I work with the aruco library and with ROS thus I currently use this code:

https://github.com/joselusl/aruco_eye

I have this output(x pointing right, y out of the image and z down)

[image]

What I basically want is:
x pointing right, y up and z out of the image

Is there a simple way in the aruco lib definition of how to set the coordinate system? Or do I have to turn it afterwards?

So currently the aruco lib is configured like this:

```
const aruco::MarkerDetector::ThresholdMethods ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_thresholdMethod=aruco::MarkerDetector::ADPT_THRES;
const double ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_ThresParam1=7;
const double ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_ThresParam2=7;
const aruco::MarkerDetector::CornerRefinementMethod ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_methodCornerRefinement=aruco::MarkerDetector::LINES;
const float ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_minSize=0.045;//0.03;
const float ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_maxSize=0.5;//0.5;

//configure aruco detector
if(MyArucoEye.configureArucoDetector(ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_thresholdMethod,
                                      ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_ThresParam1,
                                      ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_ThresParam2,
                                      ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_methodCornerRefinement,
                                      ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_minSize,
                                      ARUCO_EYE_CONFIG_maxSize) )
```

Comment: While this is not a direct answer, I post this as a comment: We do it afterwards by setting a static transform from the marker origin to the desired position.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tuw_aruco](http://wiki.ros.org/tuw_aruco) it publishes tf, already and is easy to configure.